# Django force a admin login redirect when I enter in the home url

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-admin

Why Django auto redirect to admin login url when I enter in home url?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'django.views.defaults.permission_denied', name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
)
```

I need that when a user enter in the home url, a http 403 response return to him, but it is not happening. What happen is that user is redirected automatically to admin login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx @greg for your answer. I identified what was the problem, was a browser cache. When a clear the browser cache it is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll make a difference but try changing it from

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'django.views.defaults.permission_denied', name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
)
```

to

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', django.views.defaults.permission_denied.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
)
```